# Footer doesn't stay on the bottom of the page

Tags: jquery, css, footer

I have a web page on which I use the "Supersized" jquery plugin for changing backgrounds. I also have a footer which only shows if I put the following CSS for it:

```
#footer{
    width: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #000000;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}
```

However, when something happens which changes the window height, the content of the page goes behind the footer, and when I scroll down, the footer doesn't stay at the bottom of the page - it scrolls up.

For example, I have three divs which are shown side-by-side, but when the window resizes under 900px of width, the divs are shown one under the other, and so the window height changes. That's when the divs go behind the footer, and it scrolls up along with them.

I have tried `position: relative` and `position: static`, but then it doesn't even show, even with high values of z-index. I think this "not-showing" is because of the plugin I  use for background images. I have also tried some jquery functions when window changes height, but no results there either.
Any ideas? Thank you in advance...

Comment: `fixed` keeps the section in a fixed position in relation to the window (not the page). Is that what you want? If you want a footer always at the end of the page, you should search "Sticky" footer. In that case, you can't do it in CSS alone, since it depends on the structure of your HTML which you didn't show here.

Answer (score 3):

Here is example:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

main {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
   header
  </header>
  <main>
   main
  </main>
  <footer>
   footer
  </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is keep your footer at the bottom of your "page content" AND visible, then I would advise you to assign `height:100%` your `html` tag and your `body` tag in your CSS. On the other hand if you want the footer to stay at the bottom of the "Browser Window/Viewport" then you will want to look up the ["Making a footer stay put with CSS" by ***"JONATHAN LONGNECKER"***.](http://fortysevenmedia.com/blog/archives/making_your_footer_stay_put_with_css/) Hope I have helped!  ***Athena***
***@athenacreations.org***